# Bad block count (early - later)?

Tags: ssd

SSD drive summary Gigabyte GP-GSTFS31240GNTD. Estimated life remaining 99% ; drive health good. Data from SSD tool box: -bad block count (early) value 347; -bad block count (later) value 0.My question is what it means early and later bad blocks? Do i have bad blocks on SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early bad blocks are blocks that are detected as bad at the factory. This is a normal part of the production process.

Later bad blocks are blocks that have gone bad since the drive left the factory. You have none, which is good.